# How can I find the minimum number of lines to cover all zeros in a matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, graph-theory, hungarian-algorithm

I’m working on a problem where I have an **n x n** matrix, and I need to determine the smallest number of lines (both horizontal and vertical) that cover all the zeros in the matrix. Essentially, I want to find an optimal way to assign these lines to minimize the total coverage.

Here is an Example:

```
(0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

The solution musst be:

```
(x, x, x, x, x)
(1, 1, x, 1, 1)
(x, x, x, x, x)
(1, 1, x, 1, 1)
(x, x, x, x, x)
```

in that case the min number of lines are 4.

is there any olgorithm to solve it?

I tried to create an 2d array, where i could see the sum of zeros in a line and coulm.

The Array for the Example above:

```
{ 
  [0, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1]
  [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

and in my Algorithm i picked the biggest one on the Array and covered the line (set them to false) so i dont have acces on them again. And added 1 to Linelength. But it doesent work for longer lines and coulmns.

After covering the coulmn with the larges number:

```
{ 
  [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1]
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

Comment: Picking the line with the most zeroes on it is not a good idea.

Answer (score 7):

Imagine bipartite graph, where left part contains column numbers `Xi`, right part contains row numbers `Yi`, and every zero from matrix defines an edge between corresponding row and column.

[image]

[Kőnig theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)) says that maximum matching (blue edges) is equal to minimum vertex cover (red columns or rows), so every edge (zero in matrix)  - both blue and gray - is covered by some red vertex (column or row).

So apply any suitable implementation of maximum bipartite matching algorithm (like [maximum_matching](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.matching.maximum_matching.html) in Python networkx library)

Answer (score 1):

It can also be formulated as an integer linear program.

Let:

- h<sub>i</sub> equal `1` if a line covers row `i` and equals `0` otherwise; and
- v<sub>j</sub> equal `1` if a line covers column `j` and equals `0` otherwise.

Then the formulation is:

min Σ<sub>i</sub>h<sub>i</sub> + Σ<sub>j</sub>v<sub>j</sub>

subject to:

h<sub>i</sub> + v<sub>j</sub> >= 1 for all `i,j` for which the element at row `i`, column `j` is a zero.

All variables can equal zero or one only.